# Jmeter string functions through user defined variable

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am putting some jmeter string functions in a user defined variable like below:

```
testdata = ${__char(165)}${__char(165)}My${__unescape(\r\n)}Deepak${__unescape(\r\n)}Play${__changeCase(Deepak\, change case,UPPER,)}
```

But when I am passing this value in request Body Data as ${testdata}, jmeter string functions are not resolving and I see below request in view result tree listener Request Body tab:

```
${__char(165)}${__char(165)}My${__unescape(\r\n)}Deepak${__unescape(\r\n)}Kumar${__changeCase(Deepak\, change case,UPPER,)}
```

However, when I pass above same data directly in request Body Data instead of ${testdata}, it works perfectly fine with all string functions resolving in view result tree listener request body data.

I am using Jmeter 5.3 on Windows 10 with OpenJDK 14.0.1. One of my colleagues is not facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue using latest stable [JMeter 5.3](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-5.3):

[image]

In the vast majority of cases if JMeter doesn't do what it is supposed to be doing you can figure out the reason from [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) so it worth checking it for any suspicious entries

Comment: yes checked the log. actually my UDV was not resolved due to some issues with other UDVs having similar string functions. so when deleted problematic old UDVs, my UDV started working fine. Any idea why this happened for my UDV?   getting this WARN in info for some old UDV 2020-10-21 14:40:35,502 WARN o.a.j.e.u.FunctionParser: Probably an invalid function string: \r\n}c=IN IP4.....